# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: owner for class: Mother

Tags: groovy, closures

I'm working on the following code:

caught exception at 'this.owner' which in the Closure of birth method.

```
class Mother {
            int field = 1
            int foo(){
                return 2
            }
            Closure birth(param){
                def local = 3
                def closure = {caller -> [this,field,foo(),local,param,caller,this.owner]} 
                return closure
            }
        }

        Mother m = new Mother();
        closure = m.birth(4);

        context = closure.call(this);
        println context[0].class.name

        assert context[1..4] == [1,2,3,4]
        assert context[5] instanceof Script
        assert context[6] instanceof Mother

        fClosure = m.birth(4);
        sClosure = m.birth(4);
        assert false == fClosure.is(sClosure)
```

Which, when run finishes with:

> 'this.owner' caught groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such
>   property: owner for class: Mother

Why is that?

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It all works well, please have a look [here](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#closure-owner), especially:

> `this` corresponds to the enclosing class where the closure is defined

Since corresponding class is `Mother` and it has no `owner` field nor property defined it fails with MPE. If you define `owner` on `Mother` class it will run (and possibly fail with another exception).

Comment: it`s right that this corresponds to the enclosing class where the closure is defined. To get rid of "this", there's no mistake in testing.

Comment: @BobJao if my answer solves the problem please accept it.